# Running grunt build using batch file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Can we specify loading of `gruntfile.js` from a particular location in my project folders.Its like i had grunt installed in some location in my project, I had `gruntfile.js` in different location,Now I want to use that `gruntfile.js` while running grunt. is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gruntfile.js-file needs to be in the root of your project. From the grunt website:

> The Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee file is a valid JavaScript or
>   CoffeeScript file that **belongs in the root directory** of your project,
>   next to the package.json file, and should be committed with your
>   project source.

And assuming you have the [Grunt-CLI installed](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli) you could run a `.bat`-file in your project, either from the root or changing into the root with `cd`, and then use your grunt-command:

```
@echo OFF

echo Starting Grunt Watcher
start "Watcher" /D %~dp0 cmd /c grunt watch

echo Starting Node Server
start "Server" /D %~dp0 cmd /c grunt serve

echo Building Project
grunt build
```

(Example taking from my projects-batch-files, where I start some grunt-tasks in new windows)